# how to use json on twitter typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js

I have a json like this:

```
{"num": ["test", "test group event"]}
```

I want to use [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/),
but their json is like this:

```
["Andorra","United Arab Emirates"]
```

How can I use my json for the example below?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        var countries = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer : Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            limit : 10,
            prefetch : {
                url    : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysearch/',
                filter : function(list) {
                    return $.map(list, function(country){ 
                        return { 
                            name : country 
                        };
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        countries.initialize();
        $('#prefetch .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name : 'countries',
            displayKey : 'name',
            source : countries.ttAdapter()
        });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

Update:

My json is coming from the server(http://rroyales.webfactional.com/mysearch/1.json) so if possible I think we have to use prefetch to get json from the server. I don't want to use getjson to capture it in a variable or is there an easier way to capture it in a variable?

Update 2:

[what is wrong with my json coming from haystack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002963/what-is-wrong-with-my-json-coming-from-haystack) - created a new question related to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

This is how your bloodhound should look like

```
var dataSource = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('item'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: "http://jsbin.com/nixalofara/1.json",
        filter: function (data) {
            return $.map(data['num'], function (item) {
                return {
                    item: item
                };
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And typeahead like this

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true
}, {
    displayKey: 'item',
    source: dataSource.ttAdapter()
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/5/)

---

<del>`var data = {"num": ["one", "two"]};`

This is how your bloodhound should look like for data like above

    var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      local: $.map(data['num'], function(item) { return { value: item }; })
    });


And typeahead like this 

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
      highlight: true
      }, {
      source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
    });



Hope this helps.</del>

Comment: My json is coming from the server(http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysearch/json). see updated question.

Comment: wow, your json is working but not with mine. http://rroyales.webfactional.com/mysearch/1.json

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002963/what-is-wrong-with-my-json-coming-from-haystack> - created a new question related to this

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is a property within the larger json object, I'm pretty sure you could do something like this:

```
var myJson = {"num": ["one", "two"]}; //capture your json object in a variable
var myArray = myJson.num; //myArray will now equal ["one", "two"]
```

And then, near the bottom of the code you list, you'd need to update the `typeahead` call accordingly.

Comment: My json is coming from the server(http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysearch/json). see updated question.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002963/what-is-wrong-with-my-json-coming-from-haystack> - created a new question related to this