# what is wrong with my json coming from haystack

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, typeahead.js

[how to use json on twitter typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995270/how-to-use-json-on-twitter-typeahead) - related to this question

I have a json that I want to use with typeahead 
I have a json like this:

```
{"num": ["test", "test group event"]}
```

this is the url of my json http://rroyales.webfactional.com/mysearch/1.json

this is the url of the json that is working http://jsbin.com/nixalofara/1.json

```
{
  "num": ["one", "two", "three"]
}
```

I think they are the same but my json doesn't work with typeahead.

If it helps this is my django view

```
def autocomplete(request):

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(subject_auto='test')
    suggestions = [result.object.subject for result in sqs]
    the_data = json.dumps({
        'num': suggestions
    })
    return HttpResponse(the_data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Can you show frontend part (especially typeahead initialization)?

Comment: clear your localStorage and try again. I believe it should work

Comment: @michael <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995270/how-to-use-json-on-twitter-typeahead> - related to this question </br>

Comment: @dhiraj I tried to clear everything from my browser. even add window.localStorage.clear(), localStorage.clear(); to my javascript code but nothing works. can you try it in your computer?

Comment: I cannot try on my computer because of same origin policy. I tried and rroyales.web.... did not let me do a fetch on it

Comment: also, do you have any errors on console ?

Comment: no errors on console but why is http://jsbin.com/nixalofara/1.json working if the problem is jsonp?

Comment: I'll try to use remote in typeahead

Comment: even remote doesn't work so could be a problem with my json in django. I'll try jquery ui autocomplete also.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how jsbin makes it work, but it works. For your server it won't let me work because of origin policy

Comment: which page of http://rroyales.webfactional.com/ uses it ?

Comment: I didn't put it on the server just on my local maybe i'll try it some other time. I have to work on something else for now.

Comment: I tried it one last time and it did work, just got lazy putting it on my local server. sorry for the wasted time, if you want to get credit for the answer just post the same origin policy. thanks again. I did upvote your comments. ty